# How can there be multiple GraphQL nodes with the same ID?

Tags: neo4j, graphql

I am using GRAND stack - neo4j database and apollo server. Also using the augmentedSchema of neo4j-graphql-js. This adds more types and mutations to the GraphQL schema.

I have a type Option with the following typedef:

```
type Option {
  id: ID
  name: String
  position: Int
  values: [String]
}
```

Using the CreateOption mutation generated by neo4j-graphql-js, I am able to create an Option. The problem I am facing is that I can create multiple options with the same ID.

```
mutation {
  opt1: CreateOption(id: 1, name: "Test") {
    id
  }
  opt2: CreateOption(id: 1, name: "Test 2") {
    id
  }
}
```

The result of the above mutation is

```
{
  "data": {
    "opt1": {
      "id": "1"
    },
    "opt2": {
      "id": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

Why is neo4j allowing two nodes with the same ID? How can I ensure nodes with unique IDs in neo4j?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Neo4j concept of **Id** is a bit "different" from common understanding, and id is nothing more than **an offset of object within the store file**. Neo4j has all the control about id itself.

Even more, if you will remove object with Id `40`, corresponding bytes in the store file will become vacant. And in the future you could get another object with id `40`.

There is one more trick about `id` of objects: **Neo4j id property called `<id>` instead of `id`**. And property `id` from your example is the same as `name`. For example, I've created two objects on my local Neo4j:

```
╒═════════════════════════════════╕
│{"name":"test1","id":1,"<id>":47}│
├─────────────────────────────────┤
│{"name":"test2","id":1,"<id>":64}│
└─────────────────────────────────┘
```

To make `id` unique you have to create a [constraint](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/schema/constraints/) manually. Here is a CYPHER example:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (option:Option) ASSERT option.id IS UNIQUE
```